# Umbraco multisite (around 30 sites) in a single instance along with flexible load balancing in Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service, multisite

We have a new requirement, summary follows,

1. Around 30 sites to be developed.
2. Should use Umbraco.
3. All the sites should need have a common Umbraco backend.
4. Single SQL DB.
5. Some of the sites will be bilingual.
6. Load balancing architecture required.

We did the POC for the same with 3 sites in a single instance of umbraco by adding root nodes and assigning proper host name, permissions etc and it worked fine.

But in the real case, will it work smoothly ?

We checked the following article regarding flexible load balancing in Umbraco and planned to move with Azure as it is mentioned as the first choice in the article [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/flexible).

Is anyone has any similar kind of experience ?
Please share, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Azure Web Apps support Built-in autoscale and load balancing. I assumed that web apps leverage [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing). ARR Affinity is enabled on your Azure App Service by default. This means that if you are running multiple instance of your App Service, clients will be directed to the same instance for each request. For more details, you could refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/03/setting-application-request-routing-arr-affinity-for-your-azure-app-service/).

Also, you could leverage [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) with your azure web app for load balancing, which could distribute the traffic to your web app endpoints in different datacenters (global route traffic).

Here are some tutorials, you could refer to them:

- [Create a Traffic Manager profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-create-profile)
- Scale up your app by changing the pricing tier, then you could get more CPU, memory, disk space, etc. For more details, you could refer to [Scale up your pricing tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-scale#scale-up-your-pricing-tier).
- Scale out your app to multiple instances manually or automatically based on your configured performance peaks. For more details, you could refer to [Scale instance count manually or automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-how-to-scale?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-web%2ftoc.json).